# Improving this longwinded and repetative sql script

Tags: php, mysql

I've been learning about DRY code and my code isn't DRY...

For example, I have a custom CMS and I save basically a name, content and a publish status for a few things... like an article, a user, a event. To submit a form, I submit to a file (process.php) which has a switch in it like so:

```
switch($_POST['process']) {


case 'speaker':

    if($_POST['speaker_id']) {

        $sql = '
            UPDATE speakers 
            SET speaker_name="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['speaker_name']) . '",
            speaker_content="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['speaker_content']) . '",
            speaker_status="' . $_POST['speaker_status'] . '"
            WHERE speaker_id="' . $_POST['speaker_id'] . '"
            LIMIT 1
        ';

    } else {

        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO speakers 
            SET speaker_name="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['speaker_name']) . '",
            speaker_content="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['speaker_content']) . '",
            speaker_status="' . $_POST['speaker_status'] . '"
        ';

    }


    mysql_query($sql);  

    if($_POST['speaker_id']) {

        header('Location: speakers?speaker_id=' . $_POST['speaker_id']);        

    } else {

        header('Location: speakers?speaker_id=' . mysql_insert_id);

    }

break;





case 'event':

    if($_POST['event_id']) {

        $sql = '
            UPDATE events 
            SET event_name="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['event_name']) . '",
            event_content="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['event_content']) . '",
            event_status="' . $_POST['event_status'] . '"
            WHERE event_id="' . $_POST['event_id'] . '"
            LIMIT 1
        ';

    } else {

        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO events 
            SET event_name="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['event_name']) . '",
            event_content="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['event_content']) . '",
            event_status="' . $_POST['event_status'] . '"
        ';

    }


    mysql_query($sql);  

    if($_POST['event_id']) {

        header('Location: events?event_id=' . $_POST['event_id']);      

    } else {

        header('Location: events?event_id=' . mysql_insert_id);

    }

break;


case 'article':

    if($_POST['article_id']) {

        $sql = '
            UPDATE articles 
            SET article_name="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['article_name']) . '",
            article_content="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['article_content']) . '",
            article_status="' . $_POST['article_status'] . '",
            article_modified="' . $_POST['article_modified'] . '"
            WHERE article_id="' . $_POST['article_id'] . '"
            LIMIT 1
        ';

    } else {

        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO articles 
            SET article_name="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['article_name']) . '",
            article_content="' . mysql_escape_string($_POST['article_content']) . '",
            article_status="' . $_POST['article_status'] . '"
        ';

    }


    mysql_query($sql);  

    if($_POST['article_id']) {

        header('Location: articles?article_id=' . $_POST['article_id']);        

    } else {

        header('Location: articles?article_id=' . mysql_insert_id);

    }

break;




}
```

Despite some basic variations, like different table names and column names, and perhaps there sometimes being a couple more or less columns to populate, the code is literally the same and programming like this feels more like data entry than creativity.

I imagine there's a way to create a class for this so that all the below code could be achieved in 1/3 the amount. Is there some sort of streamlined mysql insert / update method/strategy?

In my head, I'm thinking if I name all my inputs the same as they are in the table, ie if the column is called 'speaker_name' and the input is..

```
<input type="text" name="speaker_name" />
```

...I wonder if I could have a function which went through the $_POST array and simply updated the appropriate fields. Is this sound logic?

Perhaps I would have a hidden input in the form which was the 'table' variable which let the function know which table to update and it takes care of the rest.

Excuse me while I just thought out-loud. Any ideas would be really cool!

**My newbie solution**
Here's what I have i got working

```
if($_POST['id']) {

  $sql = 'UPDATE ';

} else {

  $sql = 'INSERT INTO ';

}

// number of rows in array
$total = count($_POST);
// number of commas = total of values minus 1
$commas = $total - 1;
// starting number
$count = 1;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

  if($count == 1)
{

  $sql .= mysql_real_escape_string($value) . ' SET ';

}
else
{

if(    $count < $total    )
{

 $sql .= $key . '="' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '"';

if($count != $commas)
{

  $sql .= ', ';

}

    }
    elseif(    $_POST['id']    ) 
    {

    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . $key . '="' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '"';

    }


  }

$count = $count + 1;


}

mysql_query($sql);

if($_POST['id']) {

  header('Location: ' . $_POST['process'] . '?id=' . $_POST['id'] . '');


} else {

header('Location: ' . $_POST['process'] . '?id=' . mysql_insert_id());

}
```

To do this means my form designs need to have a pretty strict setup ie the first hidden input holds the table name, the last input is the id number of the row in the table being edited (if it exists).

I know its far from good... but a lot better than the hundreds of lines it previously took.

Comment: Er...isn't there a problem with this INSERT INTO MYTABLE SET... syntax everyone is using?

Comment: Is there something bad about 'insert into table set ' syntax?

Comment: using mysql_real_escape_string on field name is useless, not to say more expressive term

Comment: It should be INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES ... Using SET is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) some flaws in your concept

- **every** piece of data you're going to put into quotes in your query, should be processed with 
  mysql_real_escape_string, as you cannot know what can be inside.
- **never** use a table name passed from the client side. there can be malicious code instead of mere table name as well.
- same for the field names. **every** *identifier* should be hardcoded in your script.

2) as for the DRY - it's simple. just note similar parts in your code and put them into function.     only fields differ? okay, make a function that take fields list and produce an SQL statement of them.

Luckily, Mysql let us use similar syntax for both insert and update. So, a very simple function like this one can help:

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

So, you can make your code shorter:

```
case 'speaker':

  $table = "speakers";
  $fields = explode(" ","speaker_name speaker_content speaker_status");

  if(isset($_POST['speaker_id'])) {
    $id = intval($_POST['speaker_id']);
    $query  = "UPDATE $table SET ".dbSet($fields)." WHERE id=$id";
  } else {
    $query  = "INSERT INTO $table SET ".dbSet($fields);
  }
  mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);  
  if($_POST['speaker_id']) $id = mysql_insert_id();
  header('Location: speakers?speaker_id='.$id);        

break;
```

if all your actions are such alike, you can make more high leveled functions:

```
case 'speaker':

  $table = "speakers";
  $fields = explode(" ","speaker_name speaker_content speaker_status");

  if(isset($_POST['speaker_id'])) {
    $id = intval($_POST['speaker_id']);
    dbUpdate($table,$fields,$id);
  } else {
    $id = dbInsert($table,$fields);
  }
  header('Location: speakers?speaker_id='.$id);        
  exit;

break;
```

and even more high level

```
case 'speaker':

  $table = "speakers";
  $fields = explode(" ","speaker_name speaker_content speaker_status");
  $id = dbMagic();
  header('Location: speakers?speaker_id='.$id);        
  exit;

break;
```

But I won't go into that. I'd stop at 1st option, because it's pretty straightforward and there are always some little things not fit into such a broad concept.

Comment: A lot of pointers and tips there. I'm studying this getting my head around it.

Comment: @Keen yeah and even more than it seems :) feel free to ask

Comment: Cheers Col. I am aware of the security issue in having transparent db table names and columns - but I figure since this is a private backend nobody but the system users will access, with each page session logged and protected that it wouldn't pose an issue? I would not do something like this on a open website.

With your solution, I'm still having to break the page into cases which I'm trying to avoid. I guess not being a ninja at code I have to make a sacrifice :)

Answer (score 1):

While your alignment of column names and perhaps a hidden form field for table name would be quicker to code and more elegant to code against you would be opening yourself up to someone spoofing an HTML file to control the inserts to a table!  Consider refactoring in other ways to optimize your library.  Keep thinking / you're bound to come up with a better solution within the context of your problem domain.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one has some base models to do this, for example (don't be to harsh about it's failtings, I just want to give a short example):

```
class Speaker {
    function __construct($data){
         foreach($data as $key => $value) $this->$key = $value;
    }
    function save(){
        $query = 
            ($this->speaker_id ? 'UPDATE ':'INSERT INTO').' speakers '
            ."SET speaker_name='%s',
              speaker_content='%s',
              speaker_status='%s'"
            .($this->speaker_id ? ' WHERE speaker_id=%d ':'');
        mysql_query(sprintf($query(
             mysql_real_escape_string($this->speaker_name),
             mysql_real_escape_string($this->speaker_content),
             mysql_real_escape_string($this->speaker_status),
             intval($this->speaker_id)));
        if(!$this->speaker_id) $this->speaker_id = mysql_insert_id();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
switch($_POST['process']) {
   case 'speaker':
       $speaker = new Speaker($_POST);
       $speaker->save();
       header('Location: /speakers?speaker_id='.$speaker->speaker_id);
```

But for new projects, I would suggest a more complete MVC pattern (where Event & Speaker can be subclasses from some base databasemodel, possibly able to generate some form based on settings), and use *prepared statements*, they will make your sql queries easier & safer. **never** use addslashes, for good ol' mysql_query use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: And, yes, it's probably riddled with bugs, it's just an illustration & it's 3AM here now... Time to go..

Comment: Yes, one has to leave something to work on ;P extending a base class & a proper controller & factory could solve that. What am I still doing here? Sleep now... sleeeeeeeep....sleeeeeeeeeeep....

Comment: Not necessarily. As long as you don't need to support edge cases, why bother with those. And it would be DRY, as far as the question is concerned :P

Comment: seriously, I have never seen in my life when "extending a base class & a proper controller & factory" become less code than just some code you have to work. usually such a machinery take 10-100x times more space.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: that's either incompetence, or the desire to put more flexibility in later on. Really, with a limited set of desired functionality this could be lean & mean. Don't confuse it with those _'I have to be able to do everything'_-frameworks.